# NodeJS, how to render static HTML with Express 4?

Tags: node.js, express, rendering

I need to render HTML files in express 4, I write something like this but not works good.

```
  app.route('/form1').get(function(req,res){
        res.sendfile('./public/danial/forms/form1.html');
  });
```

This code can send the HTML file ,but it exactly send the HTML file and don't send css or js files that HTML file need them ,this is the logs :

```
   GET /form1 304 2.743 ms - -
   GET /css/bootstrap.css 404 2.284 ms - -
   GET /css/bootstrap-theme.css 404 2.193 ms - -
   GET /css/bootstrap-switch.css 404 2.226 ms - -
   // and many others
```

I need to do something like this:

```
   app.get('/', function(req, res) {
      res.render('index.html');
   });
```

how can I fix it?

(many other questions are for express 3 and I can't find answer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I myself find my answer.I use `ejs` template and change my extension of `HTML` files to `ejs` and render them and for needed files I use public folder.

Answer (score 5):

**Render HTML in Express 4 without a View Engine**

take the following directory structure for example..

```
-> root
   -> node_modules
      -> express
      -> html
   -> public
      -> pages
         -> index.html
   -> app.js
```

**app.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var app     = express();
var path    = require("path");

// set static directories
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+ '/public/pages/index.html'));
});

var port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
app.listen(port);
console.log('Listening on port ',  port);
```

**Note:** If you get this error.. `Cannot find module 'html'` Its because you are missing the HTML node module. Run `npm install html` command from your project root to fix this issue.

Answer (score 4):

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.render('./public/danial/forms/form1.html');
});
```

[EDIT]

To render static html files use the static middleware:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

What this does is tell express to look for static files in the public directory of the application.

Comment: Error: `Cannot find module 'html'`

Comment: To render static html files use the static middleware: "app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));"

Comment: I added it ,but not works yet.redirect works fine  with public dir.

Comment: but I don't want to use redirect.

Answer (score 0):

**Example of render static HTML with Node Js Express 4**

Dir struct.:

```
-> root
   -> node_modules
   -> views
      -> index.html
   -> app.js
```

app.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var path    = require("path");
var engines = require('consolidate');
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'views')));
app.engine('html', engines.mustache);
app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.render('index.html');
});

app.listen(8080);
```