# Showing index.html file with node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

This is my first topic, and I'm not really that great with js, but how do I get my index.html file to show up? This is what I have.

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000


app.get("/", function (req, res) {
    res.send("hello!")
});

app.listen(PORT, function () {
    console.log("Server is running on localhost:" + PORT);
});
```

app.js and index.html are in the same directory. Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [NodeJS, how to render static HTML with Express 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25270434/nodejs-how-to-render-static-html-with-express-4)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using the following code into app.get function

res.sendFile(__dirname+/index.html");